# Is O(n!) same as O((n+1)!)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Because O(n<sup>2</sup>) is same as O((n+k)<sup>2</sup>) where k is any constant. Hence can the above statement be true with the same logic?

For eg:
O((n+1)<sup>2</sup>) => O(n<sup>2</sup> + n + 1) => O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Do you know the definition of Big-O? Have you tried applying it in this case? What (or how far) did you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. O((n+1)!) is O((n+1)n!), so is a factor O(n) larger than O(n!).

Going to the definition of big-O notation, there is no constant `c` for which

```
(n+1)! <= c*n!
```

is true for arbitrarily large `n`.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the definition of [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). These functions would be considered equal in the Big O sense if and only if:

There exists a constant `M`, such that:

```
|(n+1)!| < M |n!|
```

After trivial mathematical simplifications of this inequality, you get:

```
(n+1)! / n! < M
```

and finally:

```
n+1 < M
```

Is this true for all `n`s, for some `M`?
No - you can see that, for any `M` you choose, there will be some values of `n` (for example, you can always choose `n = M - 1`) for which it's not true. Hence, `O((n+1)!)` is not the same as `O(n!)`.

As noted by Nils Pipenbrinck, in practice it doesn't matter, as both classes of problems are not tractable for practical values of `n`.